# App started with another activity instead

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm actually working on a team project , I tried to launch the imported project , but instead of starting with the main activity , it started with another activity that exist on my project !

So how can I change this , and launch the app with the first and main activity ?

in fact i have 5 session in my project so now , what i have to do is to choose which session i want to come first , someone know how to do it ?

Comment: Please take a look [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hope you are familiar with Intent filter reside in Manifest.xml and also have look upon link mentioned by MD.

Comment: the launcher activity in your manifest file you need to check..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To launch the app with the first and main activity of your project you need to add below tag under application tag in you manifest file:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Here  tag is important and responsible to define your launcher activity. 
To get more information on  check this link http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

Answer (score 1):

In the AndroidManifest.xml of your project you specify which Activity to launch first by adding Intent Filter to it like the following:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```